# VS 2012 Ultimate update 4 will not compile array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, c++11, compiler-errors

So this is the problem.  I am new at this, but the same code works just fine on VS express 2013.  I have searched high and low, donated more than a little of my hair to the floor boards, repeatedly threatened the screen with my keyboard, and disabled all my extensions to no avail:

Code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main () {
        double num;
        double arRate [] {2.2, 4.4, 7.4, 9.6}, arWeight [] {2, 6, 10, 20};
        num = 5.2;
        cout << num << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Error list:

> Error  1   error C2601: 'arRate' : local function definitions are illegal    LINE 7
>
> Error  2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'      LINE 7
>
> Error  3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ','      LINE 7
>
> Error  4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'      LINE 7
>
> Error  5   error C2065: 'num' : undeclared identifier    LINE 8
>
> Error  6   error C2065: 'num' : undeclared identifier    LINE 9
>
> 7  IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed    LINE 7
>
> 8  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    LINE 7

Comment: Use '=' between [] and {.

Comment: use [tag:visual-studio-2013] :)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use the `=` syntax which does not depend on C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appropriate array initialization syntax:

```
double array_name[] = {/* values */};
```

You are missing the `=` or assignment operator.

Comment: This isn't the assignment operator, just a syntactic touch for initialization. However, the OP's syntax is valid in C++11.

Comment: Compiles just fine after I added the "=" the thing that I don't understand is why it worked in VSE 2013...I think chris may have answered this, but I don't get all the jargon.

Comment: @TheSoggyRuler Obviously one version supports this C++11 feature and the other one doesn't.

Comment: @TheSoggyRuler, For the record, it should work in 2012 with the CTP compiler in use, but at that point, I don't see why you wouldn't just use 2013.

Comment: @TheSoggyRuler Also, the thing about the "assignment operator" is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to the [Support For C++11 Features (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) to see what parts of C++11 different version of Visual Studio supports.

We can see that [Initializer lists](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm) is not support in 2012 but is supported in 2013. So you just have to use 2013 in this case.

You can also just use `=` syntax as well:

```
double arRate [] = {2.2, 4.4, 7.4, 9.6}, arWeight [] = {2, 6, 10, 20};
                 ^                                   ^
```

which works fine pre-C++11